# One trigger should trigger a pipeline Multiple times with different values by filtering data available in config

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a requirement,
Have a pipeline that runs on configuration-driven
Built one pipeline with two sources
Ex: US and UK, for which I gave the values in the config file.
And I created a single trigger for two different times.
In the first trigger, it should pick the US parameter and run the pipeline, and in the second trigger, it should run for UK.
I'm looking for the best approach.
Thanks

Comment: can you provide information about configuration file? what is the information in it?

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be one Pipeline, Two Triggers. One trigger to specify US, another Trigger to Specify UK, both Triggers firing the same pipeline.

The way this can be achieved with ease is through the use of Trigger Parameters which can be passed to the Pipeline at execution.

Here is the example pipeline:

[image: Pipeline Example]

To create the UK Trigger on this pipeline:

1. Click Add trigger on the Pipeline Authoring Page
2. Click New/Edit
3. On the dropdown that says "Choose trigger..." select +New
4. Name it accordingly and set whatever type of trigger you are needing, preferably putting UK in the name of the trigger since this will be for UK specifically
5. Click OK
6. Set the Value of the "Region" Parameter to "UK" (without the double quotes)
7. Then click Save

After these steps are completed, and the Pipeline and Trigger are published, anytime that trigger runs it will pass UK to the pipeline as a parameter that can be used in any subsequent activities.

Rinse and Repeat Steps 1-7 for the US version of the Trigger, and now you have US being passed to the pipeline via the 2nd trigger.

You now have two different triggers (one US, and one UK) executing the same pipeline and either passing UK or US as a parameter value. This gives you flexibility on when you want US to run and when you want UK to run.

Cheers!